# Redirecting index.php?p= to product.php?id= using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I know it could be easily solved i just looked everywhere and tried everything without sucess so i had to ask here ;

how do i 301 redirect index.php?p=(number) or /?p= to product.php?id=(number) with htaccess.

I thought this might work but it didnt

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(index.php|?)p\=([0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$2 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following htaccess rules. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?p=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ product.php?id=%1 [R=301,L]
```